# Excel "IF" "AND" statement not returning desired result

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula

My excel statement should identify the year I want the date to be associated with.

- If my date in column E is less than 11/1/2015, then column F reads 2015
- If the date in column E is between 10/31/2015 and 11/1/2016, then column F reads 2016
- If the date in column E is greater than 10/31/2016, then column F reads 2017

However, they are all reading 2015.

```
=IF(E2<"11/01/2015","2015",IF(AND(E2<"11/1/2016",E2>"10/31/2015"),"2016",IF(E2>"10/31/2016","2017")))
```

Comment: You should replace your dates in quotes with excels serial number system, e.g. `"11/01/2015"` should be replaced with `DATE(2015,11,1)`.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 that worked perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=IF(AND(E2<>"",NOT(ISNUMBER(E2))),"DATE IS TEXT",IF(E2<date(2015,11,1),2015,IF(E2>DATE(2016,19,31),2017,2016)))
```

This formula will also test if your date in E is actually a date in excel's serial date format or TEXT.

Comment: @callumDA damn that edit was fast...I was just clicking on edit to fix it and you had done it already

Comment: Haha, my bad sorry!

Comment: for not using `AND`,`+1`

Comment: @ScottCraner...but I did at the start for testing non blank cell, but i Know what you mean

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
=IFERROR(MIN(MAX(2015,YEAR(E2+61)),2017),"date is text")
```

Comment: slick...I like this ALTERNATIVE thinking!

Answer (score 2):

This should also work:

```
=INDEX({2015;2016;2017},MATCH(E2,{0;42309;42675},1),1)
```

I had to convert the dates to numbers so that's what the `0`, `42309` and `42675` are. There might be a better way to keep them looking like dates.

---

If `E2` is not a number then it will throw an error. You can use the `IFERROR` like with Scott's answer to avoid it:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({2015;2016;2017},MATCH(E2,{0;42309;42675},1),1),"date is text")
```

Comment: @ScottCraner, good point. I hope you don't mind I borrowed your wording on the `IFERROR`

Comment: I just wanted mine shorter than yours. :)